# CSS module being removed on path change before Framer Motion exit animation completes

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules, framer-motion

Repo: https://github.com/qcaodigital/cocktail_curations
Live: https://youthful-mestorf-0859a8.netlify.app/

I've just deployed my NextJS project to Netlify and all seems well other than the above issue. Each page has an exit animation (currently set to opacity `1' --> '0'` @ 1000ms). For testing purposes I have reduced the animation time for the "Contact Page" exit to 0ms.

What I'm gathering is happening is that the `SCSS.module` is being removed before the animation is completed as you can see the markup still on the page during the time the animation should be happening without any styles.

Answer (score 2):

Hotfix Module: *import this into your top-level component*

```
import Router from 'next/router'

export const fixTimeoutTransition = (timeout: number): void => {
  Router.events.on('beforeHistoryChange', () => {
    // Create a clone of every <style> and <link> that currently affects the page. It doesn't matter
    // if Next.js is going to remove them or not since we are going to remove the copies ourselves
    // later on when the transition finishes.
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet], style:not([media=x])')
    const copies = [...nodes].map((el) => el.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement)

    for (let copy of copies) {
      // Remove Next.js' data attributes so the copies are not removed from the DOM in the route
      // change process.
      copy.removeAttribute('data-n-p')
      copy.removeAttribute('data-n-href')

      // Add duplicated nodes to the DOM.
      document.head.appendChild(copy)
    }

    const handler = () => {
      // Emulate a `.once` method using `.on` and `.off`
      Router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handler)

      window.setTimeout(() => {
        for (let copy of copies) {
          // Remove previous page's styles after the transition has finalized.
          document.head.removeChild(copy)
        }
      }, timeout)
    }

    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handler)
  })
}
```

Then call the fixTimeoutTransition function and pass a parameter with how long you want the css/scss.module (in ms) to persist before being removed (in my case this was the duration of my page transitions).

```
fixTimeoutTransition(1000)
```

This is not my own code so apologies if this does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Found same issue on [github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18724). As a workaround (fortunately, i have a small project), I removed all files [name].module.css and moved all styles to [global stylesheet](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet)

Comment: I found a solution (more like a hotfix) that worked on every deployment I tried.

See answer below/above..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS Module, try to make it inline CSS.